# Flickity carousel doesn't work when <div> are generated with js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, carousel, flickity

i have found a carousel based on Flickity, you can check it here:

https://codepen.io/atelierbram/pen/LRkAxQ thanks to atelierbram

now i want to generate the  containing the images with JS and i made the following code:

```
<head>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="flickity.css"></head>
<h1>Image slider with Thumbnails and Flickity - asNavFor</h1>

<div class="container">
<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div id="img_c" class="carousel carousel-main" data-flickity='{"pageDots": false }'>
  
</div>

<div id="img_d" class="carousel carousel-nav"
  data-flickity='{ "asNavFor": ".carousel-main", "contain": true, "pageDots": false }'>

</div>

</div><!-- /.container -->


<script>
    var folder = 'img/';
var carousel = 'carousel-cell';
var img_thumb='120px';
    $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find('a').attr('href', function (i, val) {
                if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) { 
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
                       $('<div class='+carousel+' ><img src=' + val + '></div>').appendTo(img_c);
                       $('<div class='+carousel+' ><img src=' + val + ' width='+img_thumb+'></div>').appendTo(img_d);
                       
                    }
                } 
            });
        }
        
    });

    
</script> 

<script>$(document).on('ready', function() {
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="flickity.js">');
});</script>
```

The problem is that Flickity is not fired properly and it doesn't append any value to

the output of my code is

```
<div id="img_c" class="carousel carousel-main" data-flickity="{&quot;pageDots&quot;: false }">
  
<div class="carousel-cell"><img src="/img/100271519.jpg"></div><div class="carousel-cell"><img src="img/140178627_04.jpg"></div><div class="carousel-cell"><img src="img/200157969.jpg"></div><div class="carousel-cell"><img src="img/200157969_13.jpg"></div></div>
```

And the output should be like:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div class="carousel carousel-main flickity-enabled is-draggable" data-flickity="{ &quot;asNavFor&quot;: &quot;.carousel-main&quot;, &quot;contain&quot;: true, &quot;pageDots&quot;: false }" tabindex="0">
    
<div class="flickity-viewport" style="height: 504px; touch-action: pan-y;"><div class="flickity-slider" style="left: 0px; transform: translateX(0%);"><div class="carousel-cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/3391cc/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 101.19%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/3366cc/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 202.38%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/394cc6/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 303.57%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/5946b9/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 404.76%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/8946b9/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 505.95%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/bf409f/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 607.14%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/d92f26/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 708.33%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/d2562d/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 809.52%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/d98026/ffffff"></div><div class="carousel-cell" style="position: absolute; left: 910.71%;" aria-hidden="true"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/672x504/cca633/ffffff"></div></div></div><button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button previous" type="button" disabled="" aria-label="Previous"><svg class="flickity-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M 10,50 L 60,100 L 70,90 L 30,50  L 70,10 L 60,0 Z" class="arrow"></path></svg></button><button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button next" type="button" aria-label="Next"><svg class="flickity-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M 10,50 L 60,100 L 70,90 L 30,50  L 70,10 L 60,0 Z" class="arrow" transform="translate(100, 100) rotate(180) "></path></svg></button></div>

<div class="carousel carousel-nav flickity-enabled is-draggable" data-flickity="{ &quot;asNavFor&quot;: &quot;.carousel-main&quot;, &quot;contain&quot;: true, &quot;pageDots&quot;: false }" tabindex="0">
```

Can anyone help me to get the right output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the **flickity data-attributes**:
they auto initialize flickity. Won't work since you load your images ansynchronously (via AJAX). Thus, So you have to wait until your data is loaded and your gallery items are appended to the DOM.

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
  <div id="img_c" class="carousel carousel-main"></div>
  <div id="img_d" class="carousel carousel-nav"></div>
</div>
```

Load your scripts directly (preferrably at the bottom of your html body to mitigate render blocking).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js'></script>
<script>
    var folder = 'img/';
    var carousel = 'carousel-cell';
    var img_thumb='120px';
    $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find('a').attr('href', function (i, val) {
                if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) { 
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
                       $('<div class='+carousel+' ><img src=' + val + '></div>').appendTo(img_c);
                       $('<div class='+carousel+' ><img src=' + val + ' width='+img_thumb+'></div>').appendTo(img_d);
                       
                    }
                } 
            });
            
            /** 
            /* your images are loaded via ajax – 
            /* now you can initialize flickity
            **/
            $('.carousel-main').flickity({
                // options
                pageDots: false,
                contain: true, 
            });
                
            $('.carousel-nav').flickity({
                // options
                asNavFor: ".carousel-main", 
                contain: true, 
                pageDots: false
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

You insert your initialize function at the end of your success callback – so after everthing is loaded and your gallery items' html is appended.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Flickity being loaded twice somewhere, this cause the problem.